# Array changes not seen (by other threads?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have a recursive function which performs the following things(among others), in that order:

1. Prints the array A which is passed as a parameter
2. Concatenates some new values into it:
   A=A.concat(localList);
3. Prints the array A again
4. Runs a for loop, each iteration of which calls the function again

While the print sandwich shows correct concatenation, I notice that different(parallel?) instances do not aknowledge the changes other make. Aren't arrays passed as reference?

I've included minimal info because I feel this is some basic fact I'm missing.

Comment: Array.concat returns a new array instance

Comment: But I did an assignment...right?

Comment: Yes, but the assignment points to a new reference

Comment: As a general rule: *assigning* to a parameter variable does not change the variable of the caller. Whenever you give a variable a new value (or reference), the old value (object/array) remains unaltered, and that is what the caller of the function is still working with. NB: there are no multiple threads involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.concat returns a new instance. In order to keep the reference intact, you can concat a list like so:

```
yourarray.push.apply(yourarray, newitems)
```

Or more modern variant:

```
yourarray.push(...newitems)
```

To be clear, this will still not work if you're using multiple threads (Workers) since objects passed between Workers are cloned.

Comment: I'm just using a for loop, is that considered workers?

Comment: No, that is not a worker so the .push solution should work

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html these are for real parallelism using multiple cores.